# What was the nature of the epiphany that led to Will's proposal?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-newsroom

In the episode "Election Night II" of *The Newsroom* Will experiences a kind of epiphany while in conversation with Charlie, which prompts him to immediately propose marriage to another character. What was it about the situation that prompted his radical change of mind at that moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes back a long way....Mac cheated on Will with an old boyfriend and Will blamed everything that happened after on her.

She acknowledged a long time ago that everything was her fault and apologised and tried make it up to him but Will has steadfastly not forgiven her and still harbours some hurt feelings and has been unhappy for over 3 years since they broke up.

---

The news team have been ambushed by a fake story where they researched and fact checked and still came up short despite their best efforts.

Will:

> *Except for the things we did wrong we did everything right and he can't live with Mac taking the blame.....[he trails off]* .

Eventually he realises that, and this is his epiphany:

> *Except for the things she did wrong she did everything right*.

Will tells Mac a story about a boy compulsively shredding paper and explains that the point of the story is:

> *The boy could make himself happy by just stopping.*

In other words, Will could finally be happy if he just got over it, acknowledged that he still loves here and **allowed** himself to be happy.